# How to Marshal COM simple type -> net type

Tags: c#, directoryservices

I need to determine value of (DirectoryEntry) user.Propertes["pwdLastSet].Value
how would I marshal such value to .Net Type..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**User Management with Active Directory—How Password Modification Dates Are Stored**
http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94How_Password_Modification_Dates_Are_Stored